# Identify and mark record times using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, window-functions

Given a database table that contains a list of race times, I need to be able to identify which of the performances are faster than earlier finish times for that athlete at a specific distance, e.g. it was their best time at the time of the performance.

Also, would it be better to update this and store as a boolean in an additional column at rest, rather than trying to calculate when doing a SELECT. The database isn't populated in chronological order, so not sure if a TRIGGER would help. I was thinking of a query that runs on the whole table after any inserts/updates. Appreciate this may have a performance impact, so could be run periodically rather than on each row update.

This is on a MySQL 5.6.47 server.

Example table

```
athleteId  date        distance   finishTime 
1          2020-01-04  5K         30:00
1          2020-01-11  5K         30:09
1          2020-01-18  5K         29:45
1          2020-01-25  5K         29:32
1          2020-02-01  5K         31:18
1          2020-02-02  10K        1:06:07
1          2020-02-08  5K         28:25
1          2020-02-23  10K        1:06:02
1          2020-02-23  10K        1:07:30
```

Expected output

```
athleteId  date        distance   finishTime isPersonalBest
1          2020-01-04  5K         30:00      Y
1          2020-01-11  5K         30:09      N
1          2020-01-18  5K         29:45      Y
1          2020-01-25  5K         29:32      Y
1          2020-02-01  5K         31:18      N
1          2020-02-02  10K        1:06:07    Y
1          2020-02-08  5K         28:25      Y
1          2020-02-23  10K        1:06:02    Y
1          2020-02-23  10K        1:07:30    N
```

The data is just an example. The actual finish times are stored in seconds. There will be many more athletes and different event distances. If a performance is the first for that athlete at that distance, it would be classed as a personal best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MysQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when finishTime < min(finishTime) over(
        partition by athleteId, distance 
        order by date 
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    )
        then 'Y'
        else 'N'
    end isPersonalBest
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, one option is a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when exists(
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.athleteId = t.athleteId 
            and t1.distance = t.distance
            and t1.date < t.date
            and t1.finishTime <= t.finishTime
    )
        then 'N'
        else 'Y'
    end isPersonalBest
from mytable t
```

I wouldn't recommend actually storing this derived information. Instead, you use the above query to create a view.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this. I've just added the server version as it's only 5.6, so the correlated subquery would be the approach.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly, thank you. Also, it is pretty fast to execute, so I take your point about not storing derived information. If it had a big impact on performance, I may have considered storing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative min in MySQL 8+:

```
select t.*,
       (case when finishTime >=
                  min(finishTime) over (partition by athleteid, distance
                                        order by date
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                       )
             then 'N' else 'Y'
        end) as isPersonalBest
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1baf4869722d1cf090cd1396eb4c1246) is a db<>fiddle.

In earlier versions, you could use `not exists`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when not exists (select 1
                              from t t2
                              where t2.atheleteid = t.athleteid and
                                    t2.distance = t.distance and
                                    t2.date < t.date and
                                    t2.finishTime <= t.finishTime
                                  )
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as isPersonalBest
from t;
```